# OK Html and Css loaded into page but it wont render properly

Tags: css, html, page

I have added Css and Html code into a cms page. Problem is I cant get the page to render properly Any ideas or help would be good. You can take a look at the problem Ime facing Below. As you can see footer has expanded quite large and 2 buttons at top of page have dropped.

[image]

Comment: Please provide URL or code

Comment: Thanks  karthick url is http://www.villalife.co.uk/customer-service

Answer (score 0):

Its seems style issue in CMS page if you add this two style to CMS page you will get output like this

```
.headermenu li a {
   padding: 0px 13px;
 }

.footer-container .footer {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 0 20px;
}
```

[image]